# RegQueryValueEx() always fill 0 in *lpData while reading REG_DWORD

Tags: c, windows, winapi, registry

I have a problem with the RegQueryValueEx() function
When I use it, it fill the *lpData with 0

```
LONG WINAPI RegQueryValueEx(
  _In_         HKEY hKey,
  _In_opt_     LPCTSTR lpValueName,
  _Reserved_   LPDWORD lpReserved,
  _Out_opt_    LPDWORD lpType,
  _Out_opt_    LPBYTE lpData,
  _Inout_opt_  LPDWORD lpcbData
);
```

Here is the code who doesn't work

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int             main()
{
    HKEY        hKey = NULL;
    DWORD       data = 42;
    DWORD       type = REG_DWORD;
    DWORD       size = sizeof(DWORD);
    LONG        result;

    result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
    if(result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        result = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "InstallDate", NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&data, &size);
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            printf("The value is : %d\n", data);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Output:

> The value is : 0

I use Visual Studio 2012 and I'm running Win7

---

**EDIT:** Corrected line

```
result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hKey);
```

Thanks to @David Heffernan

Comment: You forgot to pass the argument to printf().  There's a double quote missing as well.  You do need to post valid code to get help here.

Comment: Oops, it's my fault... I edit it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running a 32 bit process on 64 bit Windows. This means that you are subject to the [registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx) and so are reading out of the 32 bit view of the registry where that value really is 0. The registry redirector is mapping your key to:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
```

Take a look in there in regedit and see that your value is 0.

You'll need to either run your code in a 64 bit process, or read from the 64 view of the registry. To do the latter, include `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` in the flags you pass when you open the key. More details can be found on MSDN describing how you [access alternate registry keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129.aspx).